# Testing for SQL injection but resulting in error?

Tags: php, mysql, compiler-errors, sql-injection

Hi i know parameterized statements and escaping data is good practice for preventing SQL injection. But i was curious to see it in action so i set up a database to see . The problem is i keep getting a error or its not injecting correctly.

```
$ans = $_POST['answer'];
$query = "SELECT username from `members` where password = '$ans'";
$c = $db ->query($query);
$c=$c->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $c['username'];
```

I tried the typical 'Or 1=1' injections and its variations and i keep coming up with errors on the fetch or it not working at all.

Comment: Escaping is not good practice.  If you use prepared statements consistently (instead of string interpolation), there is no need to mess around with escaping.

Comment: To test for injectjon one have to understand many various things, like what sql injection is, what SQL is, what query to run, what query to forge, etc. Without such understanding, an error is the most possible outcome

Comment: Thank you for the reference , how would i learn more about this?

Comment: @Dahnny012 , The link _YCS_ suggested has sufficiently more information. So you completed reading the whole thread ??

Comment: Sorry i didnt read all of it, will do.

Comment: You may also have a look at [*How SQL Injection works through URL* on Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/36881/539).

Answer (score -2):

```
$sql="SELECT username from `members` where password = :mypassword";

// Create prepared statement
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->bindParam(':mypassword', $ans, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stm->execute();

echo $stm->fetchColumn();
```